# Laravel mcamara/laravel-localization package pass to view

Tags: php, laravel, localization, multilingual

Laravel version 7.6.2

i'm trying to use mcamara/laravel-localization package.

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

I followed the instruction the they give in their github page and made some personalization that allow me to use another field instead using the id to reach .

These are my Routes:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localize', 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
    ],function () {

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.vehicle'), 'VehicleController@index')->name('vehicle');
    Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.vehicle/{vehicle_url}'), 'VehicleController@show')->name('vehicle.show');

});
```

Vehicle table structure:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('vehicle_url')->unique();
        $table->string('name_en');
        $table->string('name_de');
        $table->text('descr_en');
        $table->text('descr_de');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Vehicle Slug table structure:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('vehicle_slugs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('vehicle_id');
        $table->string('locale',2);
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This the Vehicle Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\VehicleSlugs;


class Vehicle extends Model implements \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Interfaces\LocalizedUrlRoutable
{

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {

        return 'vehicle_url';

    }


    public function slugs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VehicleSlugs::class);
    }

    public function getLocalizedRouteKey($locale)
    {

        return $this->slugs->where('locale', '=', $locale)->first()->slug;
    }

    public function resolveRouteBinding($slug, $field = NULL)
    {
        return static::whereHas('slugs', function ($q) use ($slug) {
            $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);
        })->first() ?? abort('404');
    }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Vehicle;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VehicleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('vehicles');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Vehicle  $vehicle
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Vehicle $vehicle_url)
    {
        return view('vehicle', compact('vehicle_url'));
    }
```

This is vehicle.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{app()->getLocale()}}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing mcamara</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="{{route('home')}}">Home</a>
<a href="{{route('vehicle')}}">Vehicle</a>
@forelse(App\Vehicle::all() as $vehicle)
<a href="{{route('vehicle.show', $vehicle->vehicle_url)}}">{{$vehicle->name_en}}</a> <!-- For Example Bikes/Motocycles/Cars/.. -->
@empty
<a href="#">No Link</a>
@endforelse

</body>
</html>
```

This is the array used to translate  (/resourse/lang/de/routes.php).

```
return [
    "vehicles"   => "fahrzeuge",
    "vehicle/{vehicle_url}"  =>  "fahrzeug/{vehicle_url}",
]; //The English file is the same with vehicles and vehicle instead of fahrzeuge and farhzeug.
```

Well if I type ***app.loc/de/fahrzeuge/fahrrader*** on the address bar it works perfectly and i can reach the bikes page with the proper translation, but not able to translate the ***app.loc/de/fahrzeuge/{slug}*** slug using the link from the view.

Surely i miss something. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was looking for and I gave this post it is related to the solution [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-change-the-category-translation-on-the-fly), but I use the following packages [Astrotomic](https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable) and [mcamara](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Apparently you have a bad declared your translated route, you have to go without the parameter

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.vehicle'), 'VehicleController@show')->name('vehicle.show');
```

that the route file is solved in the corresponding language

/resourse/lang/de/routes.php

This is the solution that I have used with the previous packets.

```
    public function state(State $state)
    {
        $state = State::whereTranslation('slug', $state->slug)->firstOrFail();
        if ($state->translate()->where('slug', $state->slug)->first()->locale != app()->getLocale()) 
        {
        return redirect()->route('state.show', $state->translate()->slug);
        }

        return view('front.states.state', compact('_label', 'state'));
    }
```